# FittedBox in Expanded didn't work as expected

Tags: flutter

Expanded: Expand to fill the available space along the "main axis".

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Deliver features faster'),
    Text('Craft beautiful UIs'),
    Expanded(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, // otherwise the logo will be tiny
        child: const FlutterLogo(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

I was expecting the constraint only expand the vertical axis(Y-axis), but after I use fittedBox, both vertical(Y-axis) and horizontal axis(X-axis) constraint are expanded, no matter what the property 'fit' is.

Is there anything I misunderstand about Expanded widget?

I thought the Expand widget only change the constraint in Y-axis in Column, but why I have to use SizedBox's 'width' property to prevent the expand of X-axis in Column?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question basically sums up to this:

> I thought the Expand widget only change the constraint in Y-axis in
>   Column, but why I have to use SizedBox's 'width' property to prevent
>   the expand of X-axis in Column?

To understand why you need to give a width property with a parent `SizedBox` you need to understand what happens when you use an `Expanded` widget. When you put `Expanded` widget in a `Column` or `Row` then first widgets that have non-expanded widgets get positioned, the expanded widgets fill up the available space ***along the main axis***.

The main axis being the y-axis for `Column` and x-axis for the `Row` widgets. So a widget having a height property in a `Column` or a width property in a `Row` will have no effect in an  `Expanded` widget.

For example:

```
return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Deliver features faster'),
        Text('Craft beautiful UIs'),
        Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.white, height: 100.0,)),
      ],
    );
```

But what about the cross-axis? Which is x-axis in `Column` and `y-axis` in `Row`. `Expanded` does not effect the cross-axis only the main axis.

But when you create an `Expanded` widget you are basically creating an unbounded widget. Meaning there is no bound on the x and y axes. `FlutterLogo` is nothing but an `AnimatedContainer`, which is basically a `Container`. `Container` - has a weird behavior, if you have unbounded space a child `Container` it will try to fill the full space. That is why you see it increasing in both x and y axes. But if the container has a fixed width then it will be respected as the `maxWidth`.

```
return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Deliver features faster'),
        Text('Craft beautiful UIs'),
        Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.white, height: 100.0, width: 100.0)),
      ],
    );
```

You will see that height is not respected but the width is, this is because just how `Container` behaves in a bounded or unbounded constraint. Since `FlutterLogo` widget is basically a `Container` so this is how it works.

Comment: Maybe I got wrong description, what I mean vertical axis is Y-axis. I think the question is I thought the Expand widget only change the constraint in Y-axis in Column, but why I have to use SizedBox's 'width' property to prevent the expand of X-axis in Column?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hi if the answer helps you then you should definitely upvote and if this is a valid answer to your question then please care to tick it as a correct answer. This helps the community to grow and encourages knowledge sharing.